# Two Partitions had same starting and ending sectors? How is it possible?

Tags: partition, hard-disk, fdisk

When I was practicing with `fdisk`, unfortunately, two partitions added with same start and end sectors. When I mount them individually I can see the same data on both partitions. Is it a flaw in `fdisk`? How can I fix it?[image: <code>fdisk -l</code> listing, showing /dev/sdb1 and sdb2 occupying the same blocks]

Comment: I didn't mount /dev/sdb3, I know it's an extended partition and I mounted sdb1 and sdb2.

Comment: Will you please look into the screenshot? /dev/sdb1 and /dev/sdb2 are two primary partitions and they both had the same start and end sectors? How is it possible?

Comment: And you fix it by deleting the `sdb2` partition, because the way you set it up, your extended partition starts after `sdb1`. BTW, today everyone uses a [GUID partition table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table), but your 8 GB harddisk is sufficiently retro that the old method may make sense.

Comment: You should unmount `/dev/sdb2` and delete the partition using fdisk. This will remove the entry in the partition table. Apparently the version of fdisk you were using didn't warn about the overlap. Programs like fdisk are admin tools and let you do things like this, because they trust users know what they are doing.

Comment: @icarus, *"How is it possible"*: IMHO that's a good question.  For example: aside from  `dd`, what specific command or util is even *able* to set two partitions to occupy the same block numbers?  It's not obvious to me how `fdisk` can do that.  It might indicate a bug or a hack.

Comment: Is it the result of fdisk? At least you check the status before fdisk operation (it supposed to be good) and after operation(supposed to be bad). Fix what? A flaw in fdisk? If so, modify its source and re compile. Fix the problem on the disk? Then use another flawless partitioning tool or write your own code. All these are pretty natural simple logic thinking, so should I say you never try to think by yourself before you ask?

Comment: @JohanMyréen As you said I did delete the partition and when I try to create it again using `fdisk` it was saying there was no enough space but it did last time allocating the same sectors. I think there's a flaw and I never gonna use `fdisk` again. Thanks.